# How @sample is used in dokka API documentation in Android/Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, dokka

I am generating the documentation for my public API/functions. It works well. But now I want to include the samples (Example code) also in the documentation. I know we can achieve it using @sample, but somehow I am not able to do it.

```
/**
@sample com.example.samples.Samples.doStuffSample
*/
    fun doStuff(path: String, deviceID: String, newName: String,): Operation {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

This is my Sample class in which, I have the sample codes.

```
class Samples {

fun doStuffSample() {
    Manager.doStuff("path", "deviceID", "newName", object : Delegate {
        override fun onSuccess() {
            // Success
        }

        override fun onError() {
            // Error
        }
    })
}
```

}

This is build.gradle file.

```
dokkaJavadoc.configure {
dokkaSourceSets {
    named("main") {
        skipDeprecated.set(true)
        skipEmptyPackages.set(true)
        includeNonPublic.set(false)
        reportUndocumented.set(true)
        perPackageOption {
            skipEmptyPackages.set(true)
            includeNonPublic.set(false)
            matchingRegex.set("//package name")
            suppress.set(false)
            matchingRegex.set("//package name")
            suppress.set(true)
        }
    }
}
```

}

In generated documentation, I can only see "com.example.samples.Samples.doStuffSample" below the "Samples" header.
How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.